# TypeError: fit_transform() missing argument: y

Tags: python, jupyter, typeerror, encoder

I am trying to use Target Encoder to encode categorical values in my dataset, but I've been getting an error and have no idea how to solve this issue.

```
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder

target_encoder = TargetEncoder(min_samples_leaf=2, smoothing=50.0)
X_train_encoded = target_encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
X_val_encoded = target_encoder.transform(X_val)
X_test_encoded = target_encoder.transform(X_test)
```

Thanks for your help!